# Struggle with binary substraction

Tags: math, binary

Last week I learned about arithmetic with binary numbers especially substraction with two's complement, it was pretty easy so far but something bothers me a little bit. Why is 0 - 1 = 1 with a borrow of 1?

Sure its -1 but should we get some result like 1001 (4 bits for size)? Can someone please explain?

Comment: It's not -1; the assumption is that you can't have negative results; "borrowing" from the next column is how you avoid that. It's the same reason that when you try to do 21 - 9, for example, you compute 10 + (11 - 9) rather than 20 + (1 - 9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 0-1 is not 1 in binary

0-1 **does** **not** equal 1 in two's complement with signed numbers. But its representation does have alot of ones in it: you should get `1111`.

**Negative numbers in two's complement:**

In two complement's format (which computers use) with signed magnitude, one bit is reserved to represent the sign of the number. By convention this is the leftmost bit, where `0` indicates a positive value and `1` indicates a negative value.

To get the representation of a negative number we follow two steps:

1. Flip all the bits
2. Then increment by one

Additive Inverse of 7:

```
 7=0111
   1000 // Flip the bits
-7=1001 // Add +1
```

### So why do we get `1111` when we subtract 0-1?

How do we substract in two's complement? We subtract `A-B` by taking the additive inverse (the opposite) of B and adding the numbers.

So with A=0 and B=1:

Take the additive inverse by inverting and then increment by 1.

```
 Additive Inverse of B:

 B= 0001
-B= 1110 // Invert
-B= 1111 // Increment +1
```

Now sum A + (-B) :

```
     A=0000
(+) -B=1111
-----------
A+(-B)=1111
```

Note that if we are only allowed one bit. We can't represent negative numbers since there's no room for the value.